# Загрузка файлов при помощи ajax, Jquery

Tags: ajax, fileupload

Добрые ребята, подскажите пожалуйста хороший способ загрузки файла на сервер при помощи ajax. Буду очень благодарен.

В интернете находил варианты, но хотелось бы узнать проверенные методы.

Спасибо.

Comment: Это как? Сервер обычно работает там на PHP, .NET или чём-то еще. Когда говорят об AJA обычно имеют в виду Javascript.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov выбираешь файл, нажимаешь загрузить и файл загружается на сервер технологией AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Через AJAX не загрузить файл на сервер. Технология этого не подразумевает. То, что вы видели - лишь эмуляция ajax через сабмит формы в скрытый iframe. И в этом нет ничего плохого. Существует много плагинов для jquery например, которые сильно облегчают реализацию. Вот, например http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Зря вы так думаете, и плохо знаете html5. Простой и первый найденный пример с хабра - https://habrahabr.ru/post/125424/

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, да, коллега, вы правы. Похоже я немного отстал от жизни, тем не менее - охотно рекомендую данный плагин, поскольку использовал его сам и он отлично справлялся с задачей.

Comment: Все верно, только раньше это решалось костылем в виде фрейма, а теперь есть прямая возможность работы с ним. Любой вариант дает результат, и все они имеют права на жизнь)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, насколько я вижу это обычный POST запрос к PHP файлу, про это и был вопрос. Технология сервера как была так и осталась, автор не упомянул серверной части - об этом и был мой вопрос.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov разница между загрузкой до html5 и после в том, что раньше был костыль, теперь он не нужен, но средства остались. А по поводу сервера это и так понятно что он должен быть. Человеку нужна именно технология, как лучше это сделать. Я показал вариант отличный от старого.

Comment: @Василий Барбашев, `XMLHttpRequest` - подразумевает отправку файла на загрузку, а не загрузку файла на сервер. По этому - эта технология не умеет из коробки загружать файл без сервера.

Answer (score -1):

**AJAX и PHP: загрузка файла**

Пример того как осуществить загрузку файла через PHP и jQuery ajax.
Для начала необходимо создать HTML элемент для загрузки файла.

```
<input id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```

Далее необходимо дописать JS код:

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    alert("Done!");
                }
     });
});
```

Теперь приступим к PHP скрипту, где загрузим файл на сервер, upload.php:

```
<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

?>
```

Ну и естественно не забываем подключить библиотеку jquery. В итоге всё прекрасно работает.